# Find JS class itself in array

Tags: javascript

```
const Myclass = function(n) {
   this.name = n;
   this.getIndex= function(array) {
      //how to return array index
   }
   this.getName= function() {
      return this.name;
   }
}

var array = [];

array[1] = new Myclass('Eminem');
array[2] = new Myclass('ugly boy');
array[10] = new Myclass('Slim Shady');

/// will shuffle this array (randomly change indexes)

for(let i in array) {
  (function(_i){    
       console.log('My name is '+_i.getName()+ ' I\'am sitting at index '._i.getIndex(array))
  })(array[i])
}
```

How can i get index of this class instance in array?

Comment: Well, you can't really, as `Myclass` doesn't have any idea about the parent array reference. `let i` does mean that `i` is scoped inside your loop so, you can just use `i`. I also assume that you know setting the array item is still wrong in your sample code? The only way you could reallistically go at it, is make the array an observer/proxy and add the array reference to all it's children, but that seems like a total overkill

Comment: Also `array[] =` will be a syntax error in JS, this is PHP syntax. In JS you would use `array.push(...)`

Comment: `array[] =` is a syntax error. `' I\'am sitting at index '._i` is undefined, and subsequent property access will throw.

Comment: Sry for array[] = xx, updated

Comment: Is in JS something like function_id in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Pass a reference of the containing Array.
- To get the index use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) :

```js
class Person {
  
  constructor (name, arr) {
    this.name = name;
    this.array = arr;
    this.array.push(this);
  }
  
  get index() {               
    return this.array.indexOf(this);
  }
}

const persons = [];
// Populate persons with Person classes
['Eminem', 'Ugly Boy', 'Slim Shady'].forEach(name => new Person(name, persons));

// Let's say the persons Array is shuffled...
persons.forEach(P => console.log(`My name is ${P.name} I'm at index ${P.index}`));
```